# 時系列分析のstatsmodels でエラー TypeError: arma_generate_sample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sigma'

Tags: python, 機械学習

時系列データ分析のstatsmodelsに関する質問です。

以下のコードを実行したところ、エラーが出てしまいました。

sigma引数が使用できるようなstatsmodelsのバージョンを教えていただけないでしょうか。
使用しているPythonのバージョンは3.10.11、statsmodelsのバージョンは0.13.5になります。

よろしくお願いいたします。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 12
      8 dist = lambda n: np.random.randn(n)  # 正規分布,  引数 n はダミー
      9 #dist = lambda n: np.random.standard_t(3, size=n)  # t 分布
     10 
     11 # 知りたい信号成分
---> 12 sig0_all = arma_generate_sample(ar, ma, nobs_all, sigma=1, distrvs=dist, burnin=500)
     14 # トレンドの信号（1次式型）
     15 coef_a, coef_b = 0.05, 4

TypeError: arma_generate_sample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sigma'
```

**ソースコード:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_process import arma_generate_sample
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARMA, ARIMA

from scipy import stats

np.random.seed(123)
FLAG_fig = False

ar = [1, -1.5, 0.7]
ma = [1.0, 0.6]

nobs = 1000
nobs_test = 100
nobs_all = nobs + nobs_test

dist = lambda n: np.random.randn(n)  # 正規分布,  引数 n はダミー
#dist = lambda n: np.random.standard_t(3, size=n)  # t 分布

# 知りたい信号成分
sig0_all = arma_generate_sample(ar, ma, nobs_all, sigma=1, distrvs=dist, burnin=500)

# トレンドの信号（1次式型）
coef_a, coef_b = 0.05, 4
trend0_all = coef_a*np.arange(len(sig0_all)) + coef_b

# 出力信号（トレーニングデータ＋テストデータ）
y0_all = sig0_all + trend0_all

index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=nobs_all, freq='D')
y_all = pd.Series(y0_all, index=index)

#信号だけのデータを作成
sig_all = pd.Series(sig0_all, index=index)

y = y_all[:nobs]      #観測データはｙ
y_test = y_all[nobs:] #予測精度を見るためのテストデータはy_test

y.tail(5)

y.plot(color='b')
y_test.plot(color='c')

if FLAG_fig: plt.savefig('fig_ARIMA_ident_signal_trend.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: [このコミット](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/commit/3e0ab4e5aa65dbf8defd81efae87e1ee4b490c85#diff-940c0a16056b4ac2096f4083f4add80f9b58870c90524312a7c5b9cf1627bec2) を眺めると、単に `sigma` キーワードを `scale` キーワードに変更しただけの様です。(docstring の内容(`standard deviation of noise`)が同一です。)

Answer (score 0):

お望みの結果かどうかはわかりませんが、何点かコードを修正して結果が得られました。

metropolisさんのコメントどおり、sigmaをscaleに変えて実行してみました。

```
sig0_all = arma_generate_sample(ar, ma, nobs_all, sigma=1, distrvs=dist, burnin=500)
```

↓

```
sig0_all = arma_generate_sample(ar, ma, nobs_all, scale=1, distrvs=dist, burnin=500)
```

エラーが発生したため、以下のとおり変更しました。

```
dist = lambda n: np.random.randn(n)  # 正規分布,  引数 n はダミー
```

↓

```
dist = lambda size: np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=size)
```

以上の変更により結果がでました。
どうしてエラーが出たのか原因はわかっていません。

metropolisさんの、私の回答へのコメントのとおり↓修正して実行したところ同様に結果が出ました。

```
dist = lambda size=None: np.random.randn(*size)
```

---

確認にしようしたバージョン
Python 3.10.12
statsmodels 0.13.5

【実行結果】

[image: 実行結果]

【発生したエラー】

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-8ba787bd6d92> in <cell line: 27>()
     25 
     26 # 知りたい信号成分
---> 27 sig0_all = arma_generate_sample(ar, ma, nobs_all, scale=1, distrvs=dist, burnin=500)
     28 
     29 # トレンドの信号（1次式型）

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/statsmodels/tsa/arima_process.py in arma_generate_sample(ar, ma, nsample, scale, distrvs, axis, burnin)
    116         newsize = tuple(nsample)
    117         fslice = tuple([slice(None)] * np.ndim(newsize))
--> 118     eta = scale * distrvs(size=newsize)
    119     return signal.lfilter(ma, ar, eta, axis=axis)[fslice]
    120
```

Comment: [statsmodels.tsa.arima_process.arma_generate_sample](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_process.arma_generate_sample.html) に記載がある様に、`size` キーワードをパラメータに持つ関数を指定する必要があります。なので、`randn` の場合は `dist = lambda size=None: np.random.randn(*size)` とするとよいでしょう。

Comment: metropolisさん、コメントありがとうございました。勉強になりました。